# Modifying an existing, timezone-naive scheduler to deal with daylight savings time?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

We currently have a timezone-unaware scheduler in pure python.

It uses a heapq (a python binary heap) of ordered events, containing a time, callback and arguments for the callback.  It gets the least-valued time from the heapq, computes the number of seconds until the event is to occur, and sleeps that number of seconds before running the job.

We don't need to worry about computers being suspended; this is to run on a dedicated server, not a laptop.

We'd like to make the scheduler cope well with timezone changes, so we don't have a problem in November like we did recently (we had an important job that had to be adjusted in the database to make it run at 8:15AM instead of 9:15AM - normally it runs at 8:15AM).  I'm thinking we could:

1. Store all times in UTC.
2. Make the scheduler sleep 1 minute and test, in a loop, recomputing
   “now” each time, and doing a <= comparison against job datetimes.
3. Jobs run more frequently than once an hour should “just run normally”.
4. Hourly jobs that run in between 2:00AM and 2:59AM (inclusive) on a
   time change day, probably should skip an hour for PST->PDT, and run
   an extra time for PDT->PST.
5. Jobs run less than hourly probably should avoid rerunning in either
   case on days that have a time change.

Does that sound about right?  Where might it be off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written about scheduling a few times before with respect to other programming languages.  The concepts are valid for python as well.  You may wish to read some of these posts:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170823/634824), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20828804/634824), [4](https://serverfault.com/a/554761), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694466/634824), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368158/634824)

I'll try to address the specific points again, from a Python perspective:

- It's important to separate the separate the recurrence pattern from the execution time.  The recurrence pattern should store the time as the user would enter it, which is usually a *local* time. Even if the recurrence pattern is "just one time", that should still be stored as local time.  Scheduling is one of a handful of use cases where the common advice of *"always work in UTC"* does not hold up!
- You will also need to store the *time zone identifier*.  These should be IANA time zones, such as `America/Los_Angeles` or `Europe/London`.  In Python, you can use the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library to work with time zones like these.
- The execution time should indeed be based on UTC.  The *next* execution time for any event should be calculated from the local time in the recurrence pattern.  You may wish to calculate and store these execution times in advance, such that you can easily determine which are the next events to run.
- You should be prepared to *recalculate* these execution times.  You may wish to do it periodically, but at minimum it should be done any time you apply a time zone update to your system.  You can (and should) subscribe for [tz update announcements from IANA](https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz-announce), and then look for corresponding [pytz updates on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz#downloads).

  Think of it this way.  When you convert a local time to UTC, you're assuming that you know what the time zone rules *will be* at that point in time, but *nobody* can predict what governments will do in the future.  Time zone rules can change, and they often do.  You need to take that into consideration.
- You should test for invalid and ambiguous times, and have a plan for dealing with them.  These are easy to hit when scheduling, especially with recurring events.

  For example, you might schedule a task to run at 2:00 AM every day - but on the day of the spring-forward transition that time doesn't exist.  So what should you do?  In many cases, you'll want to run at 3:00 AM on that day, since it's the next time after 1:59 AM.  But in some (rarer) contexts, you might run at 1:00 AM, or at 1:59 AM, or just skip that day entirely.

  Likewise, you might schedule a task to run at 1:00 AM every day, but on the day of the fall-back transition, 1:00 AM occurs *twice*.  So what do you do?  In many cases, the first instance (which is the *daylight* instance) is the right time to fire.  In other (rarer) cases, the second instance may be more appropriate, or (even rarer) it might be appropriate to actually run the job twice.

With regard to jobs that run on an `every X [hours/minutes/seconds]` type schedule:

- These are easiest to schedule by UTC, and should not be affected by DST changes.
- If these are the *only* types of jobs you are running, you can just base your whole system on UTC.  But if you're running a mix of different types of jobs, then you might consider just setting the "local time zone" to be "UTC" in the recurrence pattern.
- Alternatively, you could just schedule them by a true local time, just make sure that when the job runs it calculates the next execution time based on the current execution time, which should already be in UTC.
- You shouldn't distinguish between jobs that run more than hourly, or jobs that run less than hourly.  I would expect an hourly to run 25 times on the day of a fall-back transition, and 23 times on the day of a spring-forward transition.

With regard to your plan to sleep and wake up once per minute in a loop - that will probably *work*, as long as you don't have sub-minute tasks to deal with.  It may not necessarily be the most efficient way to deal with it though.  If you properly pre-calculate and store the execution times, you could just set a single task to wake up at the next time to run, run everything that needs to run, then set a new task for the next execution time.  You don't necessarily have to wake up once per minute.

You should also think about the *resources* you will need to run the scheduled jobs.  What happens if you schedule 1000 tasks that all need to run at midnight?  Well they won't necessarily all be able to run simultaneously on a single computer.  You might queue them up to run in batches, or spread out the load into different time slots.  In a cloud environment perhaps you spin up additional workers to handle the load.