# PHP time and date functional vs object

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I do have an old piece of PHP code (approximate 9 years) with a lot of time() and strtotime() calls.
The main reason for that it was because of users being located in different timezones.

Now, I do see that a lot of people say that the new objectified library of PHP should be used instead of old/plain functions.

My question is: Did anyone who migrated code from using functional "date and time" API to the new object-oriented one encounter some big drawbacks or problems?

Comment: I'd really recommend using DateTime which makes most date and time related operations easier than using the original procedural functions

Comment: @BeingSunny I tend to agree with you but only seeing how many PHP (micro) updates you have to make to adjust timezones' changes makes me wonder...

Answer (score 2):

Basically the old functions are still working. Also they don't have been marked as deprecated. The advantage of the new `DateTime` API is the improved or simplified functionality. As long as your old application does not need this additional functionality you wouldn't need to migrate to the `DateTime` API.

If you want to review the code and further develop it, I would encourage you to migrate to the `DateTime` API for the above reasons. The only drawback that I could see is the fact that you would need to rewrite that parts of the code - and(!) test it.

Comment: I'm not afraid of tinkering with the code...I'm more afraid of the fact that there a lot of timezone updates (due to different government decisions) that might need a lot of server "grooming" to avoid PHP behave strange.

Comment: Both, the time functions and the datetime api are based on the same low level code. There is no difference in the amount of server "grooming"

Comment: Are there really so much time zone changes due to government decisions?

Comment: Enough to feel uncomfortable. Even a single change of a timezone will make the app unusable until a PHP patch is created and installed.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info for this problem

Comment: Yeah, this is some *dirty sh++* I've heard about that on a Debian maintainer mailing list once, but I'm unsure what was the result. I never had to deal with such requirements. Let me try to find that mailing list for you..

Comment: I think to remember that you can configure PHP to use time zone information from OS..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74519/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

I would just store timestamps as GMT(0) all over the place, and before outputting, based on, where user is located I would reformat time value to user-fit-needs. i would get rid of whole PHP's date time ancient stuff but I would use only this call to it.   `Date('YdmHis');` so I could as previously stated just store timestamps all over the place. And use my CUSTOM class before outputting values.

Uh, and make sure to store Timestamp as GMT-0 so the reference point was at least consistent, and there you go, the best part of ancient code restructuring is when a new bloodline is created (computing power in novadays lets you not to delete old code but just write over and around it ... joke,)

Comment: Date('YdmHis') is simply using the underlying system GMT thus is not very reliable. If I would go that way I would use Date('YdmHis O') so I will have also the timezone offset added ;)