# PHP timezone issue | BST and GMT

Tags: php, timezone, utc, gmt

I have developed a piece of application which records when certain records where modified and created, so basically we take use of the `time()` function to record when a change is saved.

I am in the UK so my time-zone has to be GMT. However in the UK we use DST so in the summer we are no longer in GMT but in BST.

How would I change the timezone to be using BST (which is GMT +1). I would like to declare it in my php file so that it is easily changed. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

**When I change it to:**

```
date_default_timezone_set("BST");
```

I get a php error `Timezone ID 'BST' is invalid`, and when I change it to Europe/London, it still stays as GMT rather then BST

Comment: what about  date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-1');

Answer (score 11):

You would be setting your timezone to `Europe/London`, which automatically transitions between GMT and BST at the appropriate dates. The timezone includes this information, that's basically the point of timezones (in the PHP sense).

The PHP manual handily includes exactly [this as a sample](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php):

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
$transitions = $timezone->getTransitions();
print_r(array_slice($transitions, 0, 3));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => -9223372036854775808
            [time] => -292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000
            [offset] => 3600
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => BST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ts] => -1691964000
            [time] => 1916-05-21T02:00:00+0000
            [offset] => 3600
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => BST
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ts] => -1680472800
            [time] => 1916-10-01T02:00:00+0000
            [offset] => 0
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => GMT
        )

)
```

Comment: As stated, i have changed it to europe/london but it is still using GMT rather then BST (its one hour behind)

Comment: Then you probably need to [update your timezone db](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php). If it's out of date and there's been a change in timezone definitions in the real world your PHP won't have this info.

Comment: Can you please shed some insight as to where i should insert those files inside the timezone db into? thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info. You should use PECL to update the `timezonedb` extension. **However**, depending on how you installed PHP, there may be better ways. For example, you should maybe use the package manager that installed PHP to begin with to update your PHP version overall. This is too broad to answer correctly in a comment.

Comment: Nothing has changed with `Europe/London` in quite a long time.

Comment: @Eclipse Then it would indeed be time to clarify how exactly you think your current timezone handling is problematic. What do you expect, and what do you get where/when/how?

Answer (score 1):

The `time()` function returns a unix timestamp, which is always going to be based on UTC (which is the same as GMT).  It would be invalid for it to be adjusted for BST, or for any other time zone.

There are other functions for working with local time, and for converting the unix timestamp to a string for display.  That is where you use the `Europe/London` time zone.

`BST` is not valid, because it could stand for "Bangladesh Standard Time", or a handful of other time zones.  In general, don't rely on time zone abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Use "Europe/London" instead of BST/GMT/UTC with date_default_timezone_set(), probably the right way to handle time for an instance. This way, the timezone time is preserved throughout the time the page instance is active.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue that `Europe/London` time-zone can be wrong by +/- 1 hour from the actual time in the real world in the UK .

```
$var = time();
```

See this example:

```
print date_default_timezone_get();
print "\n";
print date('r',1698136637);
```

By default PHP uses UTC time so this would be:

> UTC
> Tue, 24 Oct 2023 08:37:17 +0000

And through third party software for our records this is the correct time the date was set.

However, using `Europe/London` there is an issue:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
print date_default_timezone_get();
print "\n";
print date('r',1698136637);
```

Which gives:

> Europe/London
> Tue, 24 Oct 2023 09:37:17 +0100

This is not the correct time, as **the time this record was made IN LONDON in the UK , the time was 8:37am**.

Solution: use UTC rather than `Europe/London` time zones.