# Installing PHP INTL in mac not getting it right

Tags: php, intl

I have installed `php56-intl` using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) like so: `brew install php56-intl`
and when I do `php -m | grep intl` it gives me `intl`

But when I check in my `phpinfo()` file, doesn't show up `intl`.

Not sure what am I missing.

**Update**

All I want to install `intl` in my computer so that I could run my `zend` application. But whatever I do I don't get it done.

> An error occurred An error occurred during execution; please try again
>   later.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException File:
>   `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/skeleton/vendor/zendframework/zend-i18n/src/Filter/AbstractLocale.php:24`
>
> Message:
>
> Zend\I18n\Filter component requires the intl PHP extension

Comment: provide some codes related to answer

Comment: All I want to install `intl` in my computer so that I could run my `zend` application. But whatever I do I don't get it done.

Comment: Anyone any idea on this?

Comment: I have exactly same problem with xampp on mac os. if you solved it already then please post answer here.

Comment: I had added answer below, that worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was, intl was installed in my mac but not in XAMPP.

Alright, after long hassle here how I succeeded:

Go to your terminal and

`cd /Applications/XAMPP/bin`

Then `php -m | grep intl`, if it returns you `intl` then it is installed. If not installed then should return `empty`.

Now, `sudo ./pecl install intl`

Will ask `specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found`, simply hit enter,

And this will install intl, also will return this message `You should add "extension=intl.so" to php.ini`.

So simply add this to your `php.ini` file and restart your apache: `sudo apachectl restart` or hard restart from XAMPP itself.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: "
checking for location of ICU headers and libraries... not found
configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works."

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue with OsX default php and not having the intl extension. This is what solved my issue:

1. brew install php56 (make sure you have hombebrew installed)
2. in your httpd.conf Find line LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, comment it
3. Add below that line : LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php53/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, for your case just change the php53 to php54.