# Problem enabling intl in MacOS Catalina with XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

i want to enable intl extension to get rid of this error 
[Class 'NumberFormatter' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oMwt.png)

i've done this solution
1. [Installing PHP INTL in mac not getting it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085079/installing-php-intl-in-mac-not-getting-it-right)
2. [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp)

another thing that i've done is installing in XAMPP/bin with

```
sudo ./pecl install intl
```

it return this error

> 1 error generated.
>   make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed

but the intl extension still not enabled, what should i do?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: what i've done is, i downgrade my php version from 7.3 to 7.2 @Steve1754a

Comment: I stumbled on a hack, fyi.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540544/php-intl-on-xampp-7-4-11-mac-catalina-10-15-7