# Magento: Adding a new TimeZone

Tags: timezone, magento-1.7

I need to add a new timezone to a Magento 1.7.0.2 site which can not be updated to a newer magento version (core files have been modified, which we all know should be avoided, but it's done already so no way to work around that). The timezone "America/Cancun" (which I use on other sites) is just not present on this install because it's a new timezone (magento 1.9.0.2 has it, for example). If I try to just change the value in the Database to "America/Cancun", the value that displays in the Magento admin is Australian time (which I guess is the default because the option I tried to enter does not exist).
Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: `America/Cancun` has existed in the tzdb since 1998.  It's not a new time zone.  It had [a significant change last year](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/mexico-quintana-roo-time-zone.html), but the zone entry itself already existed.  Whatever the issue might be, it's not because the time zone is new.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson - I thought it had been created last year when it was changed. Next thing that comes to mind is that my list of possible timezones is somehow corrupt. Do you know where I can find this list?

Comment: PHP gets its time zone data from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info