# PHP's handling end of DST in Europe

Tags: php, datetime

Europe is doing away with DST in 2021. Other countries change timezones occasionally.

How often does PHP update their timezone rules to support these changes? Where can I see a history of changes PHP has made to the timezone rules built into the language?

I have tried searching for relevant information but have only found result explaining how to use timezones in PHP. My question is more meta and is about the language itself.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP doesn't have that information by itself, but fetches it from the underlying system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3564478/318758

Comment: That other questions is a good starting point for investigating how this works.