# Getting correct time based on timezoneid using PHP

Tags: php, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to use the accurate current local time for any location in the world based on their "TimezoneId". Somestimes I'm getting the correct GMT offset. For example:

```
$localTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$currentDateTime = new DateTime('2020-01-21 13:14', $gmtTimezone);
$offset = $localTimezone ->getOffset($currentDateTime );
echo $offset/3600;
```

This returns  `-8` which is correct for today's date in Los Angeles.

However, when I try the same using `America/Sao_Paulo` as the "TimezoneId" I get `-2` which is currently not correct for this location. It should be `-3` according to Google and other time apps I have tried.

I've searched for a solution and seen different attemps which don't seem to be working me.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: You probably have to update your timezone database. Sao Paulo used to observe DST (-2), but it no longer does.

Comment: @aynber how do i update the timezone database? I only have the values of the timezoneids not the offset itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info

Comment: Thanks for your help @aynber

Answer (score 3):

According to [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil?year=2019) Brazil stopped observing DST on 17 February 2019. To get that reflected in your application you need a PHP release that includes a version of the IANA Time Zone Database updated after whenever the announcement was made. I've run your code in [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/39ein) and got 7.3.9 - 7.4.1.

Comment: So are you suggesting this depends on the version of PHP I'm using?

Comment: Not exactly. It depends on the IANA Time Zone Database used by your PHP installation. Typically, it'll use the one bundled by PHP creators but I presume that third-party packagers (such as Linux distros) can include a different version.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Alvaro