# Custom time zone in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, php-carbon

I got issue following by cancelation of using DST (Daylight Saving Time) in my country. This change doesn't appear in php library so I cannot use default time zones because `+3:30` is not support now.
Also timezone like GMT-3:30 is not declared.
Any solution ?

Unless Carbon by itself accept `setTimezone("+03:30")` but I am looking for a solution to change timezone in all activities of my application

Comment: I assume you're referring to [Iran Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Standard_Time)?

Comment: Yes, How can i set that in my laravel application?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info will help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved by updating timezone db library using below command:

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb
```

And then it need to add this line to `php.ini` file:

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```