# laravel 8 Asia/tehran Daylight Saving Time problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, dst

im in laravel 8 and my config.php is :

```
    'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',
```

now the DST ( Daylight Saving Time ) is disabled in my country ( Iran ).
but Carbon in Laravel Show it with DST
what is solution

Comment: PHP uses a timezone database - maybe this is outdated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom time zone in PHP/Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806668/custom-time-zone-in-php-laravel) or the older linked question [How to update timezonedb in PHP (updating timezones info)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info)

Comment: In most Linux distributions, OS updates provide the latest version of the [zoneinfo](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) database. It was updated most recently on 28-March-2023, and its maintainers work hard to incorporate temporopolitical changes like your recent one in Iran. php uses it, so it must nt be up-to-date on your machine.If you [edit] your question to tell us what OS you use, we may have more specific advice for you.

Comment: @O.Jones debian

Answer (score -1):

you should first add this to your app.php (config file)

```
'disable_carbon_auto_create_timezone' => true,
```

then add the mentioned code to the app.php (config file)

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',
```

please make sure to run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

this should work for you

Comment: this not worked!